# Apple Watch auto workout detection fails to detect local walks

Tags: apple-watch, activity.app

Apple Watch [has a feature that detects workouts](https://www.mactrast.com/2018/12/how-to-enable-or-disable-automatic-workout-detection-on-the-apple-watch/), including walks, and offers to record them. This feature works reliably for me anywhere but near home, where it never works (not for years). Is there a setting I missed that is required to enable this feature for local walks?

Answer (score 3):

As you have already linked, you can only enable and disable the option. All the magic of the detection is behind closed doors.

In my experience, especially for walks, it detects them best when your pulse raises.
My watch has a high detection rate for walks going uphill - simply because my pulse increases significantly.

Otherwise we could make guesses which kind of detection mechanism are run in the background. Maybe, as you stated, it is less likely to detect a workout when you're near your home. You could try deleting your home in Significant Locations - see [here](https://onezero.medium.com/your-iphone-has-a-hidden-tracking-list-of-every-location-youve-been-c227a84bc4fc).